# How to get enum values from another script (Unity)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm currently having a trouble of getting the value of my enum from another script here's my script that handles the enum

**TrafficLightHandler.cs**

```
public enum TRAFFIC_LIGHT
{
    GREEN,
    YELLOW,
    RED
};


public class TrafficLightHandler : MonoBehaviour {

    public TRAFFIC_LIGHT Trafficlight;


public IEnumerator TrafficLight(){

    while (true) {

        #region Traffic light is green
        //traffic light 1 = green
        Trafficlight = TRAFFIC_LIGHT.GREEN;

        if(Trafficlight == TRAFFIC_LIGHT.GREEN){
            TrafficLightGreenToRed ();
            traffic_light_signal[0].GetComponent<Renderer>().material = materials [0];
            traffic_light_signal[1].GetComponent<Renderer>().material = materials[2];
            //Debug.Log(Trafficlight.ToString());
        }
        #endregion

        yield return new WaitForSeconds (10);

        #region Traffic light is yellow
        Trafficlight = TRAFFIC_LIGHT.YELLOW;

        if(Trafficlight == TRAFFIC_LIGHT.YELLOW){
            TrafficLightYellowTrafficLight1 ();
            traffic_light_signal[0].GetComponent<Renderer>().material = materials[1];
            //Debug.Log(Trafficlight.ToString());
        }
        #endregion

        yield return new WaitForSeconds(3);

        #region Traffic light is red
        Trafficlight = TRAFFIC_LIGHT.RED;
        if(Trafficlight == TRAFFIC_LIGHT.RED){
            TrafficLightRedToGreen ();
            traffic_light_signal[0].GetComponent<Renderer>().material = materials [2];
            traffic_light_signal[1].GetComponent<Renderer>().material = materials[0];
            //Debug.Log(Trafficlight.ToString());
        }
        #endregion

        yield return new WaitForSeconds (10);

        //SWITCH TO SECOND TRAFFIC LIGHT
        #region Traffic light is yellow
        Trafficlight = TRAFFIC_LIGHT.YELLOW;
        if(Trafficlight == TRAFFIC_LIGHT.YELLOW){
            TrafficLightYellowTrafficLight2();
            traffic_light_signal [1].GetComponent<Renderer> ().material = materials [1];
            //Debug.Log(Trafficlight.ToString());
        }
        #endregion

        yield return new WaitForSeconds (3);
    }
  }
}
```

On the script above it changes the enum value after the `new waitforsecond`. Now here's my second script.

**StopAndGoHandler.cs**

```
TRAFFIC_LIGHT tlh;
private void TrafficLightSignal(){
    Debug.Log (tlh.ToString());
    if(tlh == TRAFFIC_LIGHT.GREEN){
        Debug.Log ("You can go");
    }
    if(tlh == TRAFFIC_LIGHT.RED){
        Debug.Log ("You need to stop");
    }
    if(tlh == TRAFFIC_LIGHT.YELLOW){
        Debug.Log ("Preparation to stop");
    }
}
```

The problem with this script is that it only gets the value GREEN only and if the enum value changes like from `GREEN` to `YELLOW` it couldn't get the `YELLOW` value but instead still green.

I've tried doing this

```
 public TrafficLightHandler tlc = new TrafficLightHandler();
```

and call my enum by doing this

```
 if(tlc.Trafficlight = TRAFFIC_LIGHT.GREEN)
```

but still the same

Could someone please help me with this.

Comment: Are these scripts attached to the same `gameObject`?

Comment: They are different

Comment: Then you need to retrieve that script first, something like `otherGameObject.GetComponent<TrafficLightHandler>()`

Comment: also use `switch` or `else if` if you care about code quality

Comment: @Johnny Thank you. Sorry forget to do that

Comment: @BoonMingProg glad that it is helpful, I will post short answer ;)

Comment: Okay. Thanks I'll mark it as the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be able to use the other script you need to retrieve it as any other component using `GetComponent<TCompoenent>()`.

If both scripts are attached to the same `gameObject` then just use current `gameObject`

```
var tlh = gameObject.GetComponent<TrafficLightHandler>();
...
tlh.Trafficlight
```

Otherwise, if scripts are attached to different object then you need the reference to the holder of that script to do actual retrieval.

```
public GameObject otherScriptHolder;
var tlh = otherScriptHolder.GetComponent<TrafficLightHandler>();
...
tlh.Trafficlight
```