# Using a script in another script c# unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, vuforia

I have a question, I have a unity code with vuforia in which I am doing a videoplayback, my problem is that I want to use a script inside another and I use public GameObject CamaraObject to be able to use it in another script but it does not recognize me at the moment of send it to call, could you tell me what I'm wrong or if I'm missing something ?, here my code:

'''C# MainManager.cs

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Video;

public class MainManager : MonoBehaviour
{

public GameObject[] videoPlayer;


    public GameObject playButton;
    public GameObject stopButton;
    public GameObject nextButton;
    public GameObject prevButton;
    public GameObject muteButton;
    public GameObject soundButton;


    int CurrentPlayer = 0;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        DisableAll();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {

    }

    public void Play()
    {
        videoPlayer[CurrentPlayer].SetActive(true);
        videoPlayer[CurrentPlayer].GetComponent<VideoPlayer>().Play();
    }

    public void Pause()
    {
        videoPlayer[CurrentPlayer].GetComponent<VideoPlayer>().Pause();
    }

    public void Mute()
    {
        videoPlayer[CurrentPlayer].GetComponent<AudioSource>().mute=true;
    }

    public void Sound()
    {
        videoPlayer[CurrentPlayer].GetComponent<AudioSource>().mute = false;
    }

    public void Next()
    {
        CurrentPlayer++;
        Play();
    }

    public void Previous()
    {
        CurrentPlayer--;
        Play();
    }

    public void DisableAll()
    {
        foreach (var i in videoPlayer)
        {
            i.SetActive(false);
        }
    }
}
```

---

'''C# DefaultTrackableEventHandler.cs

```
using UnityEngine;
using Vuforia;

    protected TrackableBehaviour mTrackableBehaviour;
    protected TrackableBehaviour.Status m_PreviousStatus;
    protected TrackableBehaviour.Status m_NewStatus;
    #endregion // PROTECTED_MEMBER_VARIABLES
    public GameObject CamaraObject;


    protected virtual void OnTrackingFound()
    {
        var rendererComponents = GetComponentsInChildren<Renderer>(true);
        var colliderComponents = GetComponentsInChildren<Collider>(true);
        var canvasComponents = GetComponentsInChildren<Canvas>(true);

        // Enable rendering:
        foreach (var component in rendererComponents)
            component.enabled = true;

        // Enable colliders:
        foreach (var component in colliderComponents)
            component.enabled = true;

        // Enable canvas':
        foreach (var component in canvasComponents)
            component.enabled = true;

    CamaraObject.GetComponent<MainManager>().Play();
    }
```

i need to call this MainManager to the line CamaraObject.GetComponent.().Play() but it said: missing a using directive or an assembly reference

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get enum values from another script (Unity)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55139204/how-to-get-enum-values-from-another-script-unity)

Comment: so what i understand its public GameObject CamaraObject contains the MainManager so if they are in different GameObject you need to get that component into a variable but it doesn't recognize the script i dont know why D: i mean it still mark a error when i put the line <MainManager>

Comment: Make sure the script in the Assets folder is actually called exactly the same as the class `MainManager`. Also make sure you have no other compiler errors in the Unity console. A little hint: rather use `public MainManager CameraObject;` than you don't have to use `GetComponent` but the Inspector automatically gets the component from the object you reference. It's more efficient and is less code ;)

Comment: Sometimes Visual studio for me also doesn't recognize newly added scripts/classes .. restarting it usually helps.

Comment: yea i check that is the same name MainManager.cs and i try public MainManager CameraObject but it said the same error if i try that i dont know why :(

Comment: i think i found the error, it was because the script wasn't in the same asset or that what i think so, ill try to finish the app so i will check if it works or no :/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Access variables/functions from another script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37341408/access-variables-functions-from-another-script)