# How can i use variable value as variable name in other script?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, constants

I have a unity project with a config file (for anim names)

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;


public static class Anims{

public const string anim1= "NameOf anim1";
public const string anim2= "NameOf anim2";
public const string anim3= "NameOf anim3";
...
}
public enum animNames { anim1, anim2,anim3...}
```

and in another script I want to activate animation using

```
public animNames name_Of_The_Anim_I_Want_To_Activate;
```

my issue is to convert `name_Of_The_Anim_I_Want_To_Activate.ToString()` into the actual animation name

which tool can i use to turn  `name_Of_The_Anim_I_Want_To_Activate = anim1` into "NameOf anim1";

I want to go through the enum, since there are several buttons each triggering another anim 
1. I don't wanna use inheritance or multiple scripts 
2. I wanna try a more elegant way than a switch statement. this is why I cant the enum to be able to reach the variable name.

Edit:
Eventually i dumped the "Static config file" idea for a monobehaviour manager
then i could have (static/const or not)
    public string anim1= "name1";
    public string anim2 = "name2";

```
public enum CompAnim
{
   Company1,
   Company2,
}
```

and use

```
public string CompanyAnim(CompAnim comp)
{
    string toRun = 
    this.GetType().GetField(comp.ToString()).GetValue(this).ToString();
    return toRun;
}
```

thanks to Camile for the elegant solution, that's exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55139204/how-to-get-enum-values-from-another-script-unity/55139727#55139727, might be helpful

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that in Anims you have:

```
public string anim1 = "someAnimation";
```

In the script where you store the actual animation:

```
public string someAnimation = "theActualAnimationName";

...

string toRun = this.GetType().GetField(someAnimNamesEnumValue.ToString()).GetValue(this);
```

This will assign **"theActualAnimationName"** to the variable **toRun**

If  you store the animations as Animation objects rather than strings, you can use those directly with the above method too.

Edit:
[Additionally you might want to look into what reflection is (this is what the code is doing)](https://stackify.com/what-is-c-reflection/)

Comment: I'm not sure i understand so let's rephrase it:
what I'm trying to do is the opposite
public string theActualAnimationName= "anim1";

https://pastebin.com/Skm7cW7w

Comment: Is your class for running the animation different for each button or the same? I'll need more info about what you want to achieve, because I'm not sure at this point. This might help: https://pastebin.com/nJhh3eWA

Comment: hi
its a different animation for each button
that's why the name separation is for,

Comment: Hi i have read again what you said and retested, it works now, its all clear and shortened my code  a lot

Comment: I've noticed you want it to run in a static class. In that case you can replace 'this' with the static class name, e.g. 'Anims'.
Also if this answers your issue, please mark my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You have to just add reference of Anims class in another script and than access variables of Anims. If you have not Static class and static members.

In your case you just acess Anims Properties like:

> var name_Of_The_Anim_I_Want_To_Activate = Anims.anim1;

This is why because you have static class and static member, so you have not need to create instance/object of a class to access variable of Anims class.

Comment: thanks, however its not entirely what im asking.
the `= Anims.anim1` part is good for 1 button, if i have 8 or 20 buttons i want to make the `name_Of_The_Anim_I_Want_To_Activate ` selectable and then convert the enum result into variable type.

this way, and with no helper function, I can config and scale it at will.
my question is if its possible at all to do what i'm asking

Answer (score 0):

Try to Add an helper function similar to this:

```
    public static string GetStringValue(animNames enumTarget)
    { 
        switch (enumTarget)
        {
            case animNames.anim1:
                return Anims.anim1;
                break;
            case animNames.anim2:
                return Anims.anim2;
                break;
            case animNames.anim3:
                return Anims.anim3;
                break;
            default:
                return "Wrong Enum Value Sent!!"; 
        }  
    }
```

**Update**

In case you can use `Dictionary<string,string>` then you could do this:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;


public static Dictionary<string, string> _AnimNames = new Dictionary<string, string>();
```

register the entries like that

```
    _AnimNames.Add("anim1", "NameOf anim1");
    _AnimNames.Add("anim2", "NameOf anim2");
    _AnimNames.Add("anim3", "NameOf anim3");
```

Create an helper method like that:

```
    public static string GetStringValue(animNames enumTarget)
    {
        var key = System.Enum.GetName(typeof(animNames), enumTarget);
        var nameEntry = _AnimNames.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Key == key);
        var nameValue = nameEntry.Value;

        return nameValue;
    }
```

so finally you can use it like this:

```
     name_Of_The_Anim_I_Want_To_Activate = animNames.anim2;

     var name = GetStringValue(name_Of_The_Anim_I_Want_To_Activate);
```

Comment: true, but I'm trying to investigate a more elegant way than a switch statement.

the Idea of a helper function inside the config file is not bad, but im interested more in if there is a way to bypass the enum thing and accass a variable value through the variable name as string.

Comment: are you allowed to use Dictionary<string,string> ? in case yes then you would need to register those values and query the dictionary instead of using const values

Comment: thanks, that was helpful
yea i used dict eventually
the only diff was that i simply returned for example `_AnimNames[anim1]` right away in `GetStringValue`

Comment: i am allowed but i was looking for a solution that is not based on data structures that need to be updated every time i make a change.
your solution is good but what i needed is more like what Camile has offered.

only downside is that it wouldn't work in a static object